# What is the Difference between "\" and "/"?

Tags: path, operating-system

For Example This Both are Opening same path

C:\Users\XYZ\Pictures
C:/Users/XYZ/Pictures/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,It's a historical problem.Traditional NT and DOS operating system uses "\" as an internal expression in VFS path.But UNIX-like system uses "/".Also,many complier considers backslash as escape character e.g."\n \r".So to facilitate the porting of different platforms and the communication across computer systems, Windows now also supports splash as a path separator.

Answer (score -1):

More programs use the backslash.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).